# how to save writeablebitmap to a new image in windows phone using c#.net?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using the below code to write text on an image. But I am not able to save it.IS there a way I can save changes to a new image or overwrite to existing image ?

```
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\DefaultImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
        {
            WriteableBitmap wbitmap = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = stringToRender;

            wbitmap.Render(textBlock, null);
            wbitmap.Invalidate();

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your generated image by calling `SaveJpeg()` on the WriteableBitmap. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg(v=vs.105).aspx